# how should i convert a uint32_t value into a char array of size 32?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, uint32-t

(uint32_t header;char array[32];)
how do I copy the data from header to array in c++ ? how to carry out this conversion ? I tried type -casting, but it doesn't seem to work .

Comment: `uint32` is 32 bits. `char[32]` is 32 * 8 bits. So the question is really, what are you **actually** trying to do? How do you imagine such a conversion should take place?

Comment: i actually want to store the uint32 data in the form of character array

Comment: size can be adjusted accordingly right

Comment: but what does that mean? Do you want to map `array[0]` to the 8 most significant bits of `header` and `array[3]` to the 8 least significant bits of `header` and fill `array[4]` through `array[31]` with 0? ... this is not something so intuitive....

Comment: it might help to explain **why** you are trying to do this, what you are actually hoping to accomplish (you may be going about it the wrong way). Right now it's just pulling teeth...see [this explanation of the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: see uint32 will have 32 digits right , so i would like to store these 32 bits in a character array. is it possible to do that ?

Comment: So, you want something like `array[0]` to be `'0'` or `'1'` based on `header` bit 0, `array[1]` to be based on bit 1, and so on?

Comment: @user8158123 it's possible to do anything if you do it the right way...and know what you want. Maybe the thing you lack is understanding that a character is 8 bits. Maybe you just want to access bits individually and a union with a bitfield struct is more what you're after. The point is *we can't read your mind* (and for that matter neither can a compiler, that's why simple type casting failed because there is no obvious conversion for what you want)

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) to get a binary representation and convert that to char array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::uint32_t x = 42;
    std::bitset<32> b(x);
    char c[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        c[i] = b[i] + '0';
        std::cout << c[i];
    }
}
```

This will resemble a little-endian representation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but I will write an answer that may help someone else. So, basically you could use `std::bitset` which represents a fixed-size sequence of N bits.

With `std::bitset<32> bits(value)` you can create a sequence of 32 bits representing the 4-byte integer. You can also use `std::bitset::to_string` function in order to convert those bits to `std::string`.

However, if you want to have some more sophisticated output you can use the following function:

```cpp
void u32_to_binary(uint32_t const& value, char buffer[]) {
    std::bitset<32> bits(value);
    auto stringified_bits = bits.to_string();

    size_t position = 0;
    size_t width = 0;
    for (auto const& bit : stringified_bits) {
        width++;
        buffer[position++] = bit;

        if (0 == width % 4) {
            buffer[position++] = ' ';
            width = 0;
        }
    }

    buffer[position] = '\0';
}
```

which will create an output like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1100
```

Here is how you can use it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    char buff[128];
    u32_to_binary(28, buff);
    std::cout << buff << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```